# How to extract value of root variable from kernel commandline

Tags: linux, bash, sh, busybox

I want to extract the value set to the root variable in following kernel command line, I don't want to use awk column number.

```
console=ttyO0,115200n8 noinitrd mem=256M root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait=1 ip=none
```

I am able extract it using following command but it depends on the position of root variable but if that position changes it won't work

```
cat /proc/cmdline | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '=' -f2
```

Any suggestions/hint/pointers ?

**EDIT**:
All answers are correct, I am accepting Aaron's answer as he was the first to reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` works better here:

```
cat /proc/cmdline | sed -e 's/^.*root=//' -e 's/ .*$//'
```

The first expression removes `root=` and everything before. The second one removes the next space and everything after.

Comment: sed works better means in terms performance ? or in terms of simplicity ?

Comment: In terms of how complex code I have to write :-) anubhava's solution is good too but I prefer symmetry.

Comment: You can combine both those expressions with capture groups: `cat /proc/cmdline | sed -e 's|^.*root=\(.\+\) .*$|\1|'`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo $root

$ cat /proc/cmdline | grep -o '\broot=[^ ]*'
root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
$ eval $(cat /proc/cmdline | grep -o '\broot=[^ ]*')
$ echo $root
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I read man page for grep  '-o' means "--only-matching" but could you please explain later part please ?

Comment: '\broot=[^ ]*' is a regular expression:
\b => start of a word;
[^ ]* => any number of any (except whitespace) char.

Therefore, the 'grep' command will get a string like "root=xxxx". 'eval' that string then set env variable "root" to xxxx

Answer (score 3):

Another one with `awk`:

```
cat /proc/cmdline | awk -v RS=" " '/^root=/ {print substr($0,6)}'
```

It uses `RS` (Record Separator) to split each space-separated parameter into a different `awk` record. Then, both the pattern and the `substr()` function can refer to the beginning of the found record.

Comment: This is straight-forward and understandable solution.

Comment: Thank you for reply yolenoyer. what is substr($0,6) means ? because if i change it to substr($1,6), it gives the same output.

Comment: $0 is the whole record, and $1 is the first field of this record. As there is only one field there, they are equal.

Comment: `awk -F= -v RS=" " '/^root=/ {print $2}' /proc/cmdline`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
awk -F 'root=' '{sub(/ .*$/, "", $2); print $2}' /proc/cmdline
/dev/mmcblk0p2
```

Or even shorter without using regex:

```
awk -F '=' '$1=="root"{print $2}' RS=" " /proc/cmdline
/dev/mmcblk0p2
```

This `awk` command used `root=` as field separator and takes everything after `root=` as `$2` (2nd field). `sub` function strips everything after space that leaves `/dev/mmcblk0p2` in `$2` and gets printed.

Comment: Thank you for reply, if possible could you please explain it?

Comment: ok I added some explanation in my answer, let me know if you have any further clarification.

Comment: I got it thank you. :) But i am in dharma sankat(dilemma), which one is better and should be chosen as an answer!!

Comment: If you want even smaller approach then `grep -oP 'root=\K\S+' /proc/cmdline`

Comment: For me second one is easy to understand, Thank you Anubhava.

Comment: Yes 2nd one is no doubt simpler and my preference too due to non-regex use and shorter command.